# MS Access VBA Function Result in Form Text Box Control

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I've written a custom VBA function and would like the output to print out into a text box. The function is simple but I keep getting #Name in the text box.

What is the proper way to set the Control Source to a custom VBA function in an Access Form Text Box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a vague question ...

```
Control Source : =MyFunction()
```

You should, of course, check that the function works. The immediate window is useful for such testing. You can also use an event to get the result and set the value of the textbox.